# Quais horários estão entre um hora e outra hora ? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, data

Gostaria de saber quais horários estão por exemplo, entre 08:00 e às 20:00 .
Pensei em subtrair dois horários, pegar o valor que me informa quantas horas possuem de diferença e somar.

Por exemplo:

```
$hora_inicio = "08:00";
$hora_fim = " 20:00";
$diferenca = "12 horas";


for($i = 0;$i < $diferenca; $i++)
{
   $horas = date('H:i', strtotime('+30 minutes', strtotime($hora_inicio )))."<br>";
}

echo $horas;
```

Não estou conseguindo atribuir os horários a uma variável.

Estou no caminho certo, teria outra forma ?

Comment: Não é só fazer uma operação matemática normal pegando o valor antes dos dois-pontos `:` e ir somando até o valor desejado e adicionando a um array? Se for mais de um horário, se for só a diferença faça como no link do primeiro comentário.

Comment: Pode ser, irei tentar fazer desta forma, obrigado !